# Mongoose, where do I define the model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building my first node/express/mongoose application. I am stuck on this error:

500 ReferenceError: ServerModel is not defined

Below is the file "routes/input.js". I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, the model is clearly defined right before I try to use it.

```
exports.verify = function(req, res){
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var serverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
  os: String,
  osVersion: String,
  createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
  modifiedOn: Date,
  cores: Number,
  memoryGB: Number,
  licenses: [licenseSchema]
});
var licenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
  modifiedOn: Date
});

mongoose.model( 'ServerModel', serverSchema );

  var inputVar = new ServerModel({
    name: req.param.name,
    os: req.param.OS,
    osVersion: req.param.OSv
  });
  res.render('input', { title: 'verify' });
};
```

Comment: I am able to use the model now but I still have a problem.  
    OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `Server` model once compiled.

I think I understand why, because each time the route is called it trys to define the model again. I need to define the model somewhere else... but I'm not sure where.

Comment: I think this question was an abomination and I would like to delete as I don't think my question was answered and its just taking up space on the Internet.

Comment: So delete it then. I put a lot of time into that answer (even made you a freaking gif), so I guess if you're gonna say it's not an actual answer then whatever; maybe you should ask better questions. Good luck.

Comment: I tried deleting it a while ago it won't let me. I got pissed off when I tried to reword the question and it got modded down. You didn't answer my question. I appreciate how much time you put into answering it but what you did was suggest a solution using something you created. That's great and all but it isn't what I asked.

Comment: Just pop open the index file and you'd see how thin a shell it is. You are asking about where to put mongoose resources and all simpledb does is do just that, gives you a good pattern to follow. Seriously, peek in [the module code](https://github.com/codetunnel/mongoose-simpledb/blob/master/index.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative answer for you since you're just starting out: [mongoose-simpledb](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-simpledb).

> *Disclaimer: I wrote it.*

[image]

> *The glitch that caused the name field not to show up at the end in the above gif was actually user error. During a test I inserted an identical record with the same username and it didn't have the name field. The final retrieval of the user actually retrieves that user instead of the second one :/*

It let's you define all your schemas in separate files in a "dbmodels" folder at the root of your app (or any folder you specify in the options). An example model/schema file looks like this:

```
// /dbmodels/Book.js

exports.schema = {
    title: String,
    publishDate: Date,
    authorName: {
        first: String
        last: String
    }
};
```

Notice how it's exactly the same object that mongoose wants for a schema. You can also define methods and virtual properties in your model file. Here's an example virtual property that lets you get and set an `authorName.full` property even though there isn't such a property on the document stored in the database:

```
// /dbmodels/Book.js continued...

exports.virtuals = {
    'authorName.full': {
        get: function () {
            return this.authorName.first + ' ' + this.authorName.last;
        },
        set: function (fullName) {
            if (fullName.indexOf(' ') !== -1) {
                var names = fullName.split(' ');
                this.authorName.first = names[0];
                this.authorName.last = names[1];
            } else {
                this.authorName.first = fullName;
                this.authorName.last = '';
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Once you have your model files setup how you want them initializing your database is super easy.

```
// app.js

var simpledb = require('mongoose-simpledb');

simpledb.init('mongodb://localhost/test', function (err, db) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    // Now you can access your models via the db object. Example:
    db.Book.find({ title: "Pale Blue Dot" }, function (err, books) {
        // ...
    });
    // This is a great place to put your application code, such as an
    // express app and then pass the db object wherever you need it :)
});
```

I wrote this module to make it easier to do the 98% use-case with Mongoose. Ultimately you just want a single object with all your models so you can use that as the API to your data layer. This module does all of that. All you need to pass is your connection string and you're good to go. However, you can also pass in an options object in place of the connection string and configure certain things to suit your needs (see the [README](https://github.com/chevex/mongoose-simpledb/blob/master/README.md)).

I also put together a [Node.js & MongoDB 101](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIPbmPUKyMI) video recently (not monetized) if that helps :)

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible to reuse the same model on different routes without your module (or another module)?

Because I am having trouble using the same model on 2 routes.

Comment: Of course you can use the same model on multiple routes. All my module does is make things a little more straightforward by giving you a single db object that has all your models attached to it. You can definitely do everything I did without my module; simpledb just provides a simple structure so it's easier to setup. In my example you can get at your models through the db object and you have access to that object anywhere you want it. Check out [the readme](https://github.com/chevex/mongoose-simpledb/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @AlexFord Why am I getting a similar error with `mongoose-simpledb`? I have used it before with no problems. But I have a relatively new project with only one model and I get this: http://i.imgur.com/Xu3H8ah.png 

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: @Antrikshy Sounds to me like you might be initializing simpledb multiple times maybe? Ensure that `simpledb.init` is only being called once when your app starts up.

Comment: @AlexFord Rebooting fixed it, actually. Do you know if I need to create a User object before I can use findOne on it? I haven't created one programmatically, but manually added a document to the database on MongoLab. Is this why my lookup isn't working? I have some computer issues so I can't test it right now, but it would be great if you could confirm.

Comment: @Antrikshy I'm not sure what you mean. If you're using simpledb then you have to have a `dbmodels` folder (or different if specified in options) in the root of your project with a `User` model defined there. When you call `simpledb.init` simpledb connects to your database, then iterates over your model files in `dbmodels` and creates Mongoose model objects for them. Lastly, it attaches those model objects to the `db` object and passes `db` to you. Now you can access `db.User.findOne(...)`.

Comment: @Antrikshy [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/chevex/18c436a9e179b2360d86) example of the two ways you can get reference to the `db` object in mongoose simpledb. If you use the callback style then you will guarantee that your models are loaded onto the `db` object by the time you have it.

Comment: I have used mongoose-simpledb before, but never with Passport. I seem to have hit all of these requirements. According to a print statement in the callback, it seems to have connected, but when I try to look the user up in Passport functions, it cannot find the model. There are more details in one of my recent questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Antrikshy, I added a comment to your other question.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I'll post more details when I can get to a functioning computer. Hard drive problems... -_-

Answer (score 3):

You need to say:

```
var ServerModel = mongoose.model( 'ServerModel', serverSchema );
```

Comment: Yeah, it works now thanks. The book I have been reading shows it the way I had it originally in an example. Maybe the book is outdated?  

Everything works now and I can see the data inside of the database from the mongo CLI, but it only works 1 time. if i try to reload the  page it gives me this error.  

    OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `ServerModel` model once compiled.

If i restart the app I can use it to add 1 more entry to the DB and then have to restart it again.

Comment: I had to take away the "correct" status because I still don't know where to define the model. I'm calling it in the wrong place, currently it gets defined every time someone loads the page and that is giving me errors. @Daniel Flippance corrected me on HOW to define it, not WHERE. Thanks

Comment: If it's happening on every request then you're defining your models in a request handler somewhere. Ideally you should define your models and have mongoose all ready to go before you even execute the rest of your application initialization code. See my answer if you want a module that gives you a specific place to define your models and a specific place to insert your application logic.